# Grayscale not working in simple TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

The MWE says it all:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{minimal}
\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \selectcolormodel{gray}
  \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red] (1.5,4) rectangle (3.5,4.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It draws the box. But the box is red. I expect it to be gray. Same with LuaLaTeX or pdfLaTeX compiler. TeXlive 2016 on Linux. Interface is TeXworks.

My first attempt with TikZ bombed. :(

Comment: (1) `xcolor` plays almost almost no role in Ti*k*Z; I am not surprise if a command from `xcolor` does not work. (2) What exactly do you want? If you want a gray rectangle, you should try `fill=gray` or `fill=black!50`. (3) `\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}`.

Comment: I am attempting to force TikZ to grayscale, even if drawn in color. I know how to draw gray directly. That is not the problem. An earlier question from someone else had reference to xcolor, so I threw that in for good measure. Passing gray (instead of monochrome) to xcolor did the trick. I had also tried grayscale, which didn't work. Just gray works.

Comment: It's curious. It works as expected for `\fill[red] (2,0) circle (1);`, but `\fill[fill= red] (2,0) circle (1);` gives a red circle. It looks as if the key bypasses the color conversion.

Comment: note that monochrome option to (x)color doesn't give greyscale, it disables colour completely so you get full black for all text or rules.

Comment: Ah, but if monochrome disabled color completely, then I would not see a red rectangle, with my original code. I'd see black or white.

Comment: The `monochrome` option is not documented (by the `xcolor` package).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `\fill[red,draw=red]` instead.

Note: Besides the comments by @Symbol1, [avoid using the minimal class.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/59109)

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\selectcolormodel{gray}
\fill[red,draw=red] (1.5,4) rectangle (3.5,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

To get all strokes as well as all fills grayscale-colored, the `\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}` option can be used. It will, however, set this in the whole document except for the included graphics.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [draw=blue,fill=red] (1.5,4) rectangle (3.5,4.5);
\draw [fill=green,draw=red] (1,2)--(1,3)--(3,3)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get red from this

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - It gives me gray on my machine and on ShareLaTeX as well. I wonder if someone else is having the same issue!

Comment: Hmm.. Shouldn't the border and fill both be gray, if that is the color model? The above image shows a red border with gray fill. My objective is to prevent the insertion of a color drawing in a document that must be grayscale (it can be reduced to gray).

Comment: as shown in the image, the fill is gray but the drawn border is red

Comment: Plenty of good feedback. Symbol1 didn't write his comment as an answer, so I'll mark this one. Still, I see that others experience odd behavior. In my case, I really do wish to disable color everywhere (except included images, which cannot be treated that way). I got the `monochrome` from something else, long ago (and yes, it was black and white).

Answer (score 3):

You can force the pgf color commands to use gray or any other colour that you want:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\let\oldpgfsetstrokecolor\pgfsetstrokecolor
\let\oldpgfsetfillcolor\pgfsetfillcolor
\def\pgfsetstrokecolor#1{\oldpgfsetstrokecolor{gray}}
\def\pgfsetfillcolor#1{\oldpgfsetfillcolor{gray}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \selectcolormodel{gray}
  \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red] (1.5,4) rectangle (3.5,4.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples!!

Comment: @cfr I'm allowed to use my own class files, surely:-)

Comment: Allowed, sure, but you should surely include a health warning?

Answer (score 3):

The `monochrome` option is inherited from the old `color` package. Description: *One special option for the `color` package that is of interest is `monochrome`. If this option is selected the colour commands are all disabled so that they do not generate errors, but do not generate colour either. This is useful if previewing with a previewer that can not produce colour.*

Here, you want colors in a gray space, so you may use the `gray` option of `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[draw=red,fill=green] (1.5,4) rectangle (3.5,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]